# TestNG - Is there a lightweight (not dataprovider, not XML) way to pass parameters among @Test and @BeforeMethods?

Tags: dependency-injection, testng

I am trying to hook my tests up to an external test management system so they can report results to it. Every test method is therefore linked to a key in the test database.

If I have an @Test method, I can set a variable with the key within it, but that doesn't help me if I'm using @BeforeMethod. Is there an easy way to provide each @Test with this one parameter, and for the @BeforeMethod to get the same parameter for each @Test?

I'm trying this:

```
@BeforeMethod
def startBrowser(Object[] testArgs) {
    println "@BeforeMethod: testArgs are $testArgs"
}

@Test
def test(String testKey = "QA-123") {
    println "@Test: The testKey is $testKey"
}
```

But when I do, the output that I get looks like:

```
@BeforeMethod: testArgs are []
@Test: The testKey is QA-123
```

Is there something obviously wrong with this approach? My maven pom says I'm using TestNG 6.9.10, so I think the feature should be activated (it's been a part of TestNG since 5.9 as far as I know).

The @BeforeMethod is located in a different file, as it's in a superclass of the test class that contains the @Test, but I don't think that should make a difference.

Is it because I'm using a default argument for the @Test method? I'm trying to avoid using some sort of DataProvider or Parameter, as these seem to be too weighty and geared toward different things, like running the same @Test with many different iterations of data. All I want to do is define one piece of data that's specific to an @Test method and then allow the @BeforeMethod to know what it is.

**EDIT:** It does appear to be caused by my attempted use of the default argument. If I try to use an incredibly clunky @DataProvider, it works:

```
@DataProvider(name = "demo")
Object[][] key() {
    return [["QA-123"]]
}


@Test(dataProvider = "demo")
void test(String zephyrKey){
    ...
}
```

That works, but it's... hideous. I can't go creating DataProviders for every single test method - it's not only cumbersome, it feels completely wrong for what a DataProvider is. Is there a better way to pass this static piece of data from the test method to the before method?

Comment: What do you mean by "can report results"? You mean something like the html or xml report but dedicated to your test management system?

Comment: I mean that I want to call out to the test management system via its API throughout the tests, including their before and after steps, if any. As a result, information pertaining to the test in the test management system must be available to the before and after steps, and that information is tied to each test method (each test method maps to a record in the test management DB).

Comment: You should have a look on qaf (https://github.com/qmetry/qaf) or allure (https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java) which are already doing the same kind of things thanks to listeners

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the available @Test annotation attributes like *testName* or *description* and access the same inside you @BeforeMethod. There could be other elegant ways to do this, but this is roughly what I did to update results to JIRA for a test framework that we owned.

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setup(final Method method) {
    final String zephyrID = method.getAnnotation(Test.class).testName();
}

@Test(testName = "zephyr_id_001")
public void test1(){
  //My test code
}
```

Edit: I did check if it is possible to add a custom annotation attribute and was not able to do so: [TestNG - Add custom attribute to @Test annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280692/testng-add-custom-attribute-to-test-annotation)

Comment: Thanks! This looks workable. I'm connecting to Zephyr as well, actually :)

Comment: Huh. This is easy to do using the @BeforeMethod because of the way it just gets the test method passed in, but is there a simple way to get this data inside the test method itself? I'm using the description rather than testName right now.

I have been looking up lots of stuff about trying to get the Method that I am currently in, since that's what I'd need to do if I were to access the annotations like I am in the BeforeMethod, but it feels clunky/dangerous. Does TestNG make it easy?